# Automatic html data extraction using deeplearning

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, information-extraction, structured-data

We are dealing with web pages, the objective is to let web crawler to extract data items/fields from them and put the data in a database table, automatically, without manually configure every html page to achieve that. We have enough training samples, we are trying to use deeplearning, there are several ways we come up with:

1. end-to-end mapping from web page to structured data in database, I want to use question-answer or summation paradigm, but current papers on these subjects are using a paragraph of text as input, not html page.  Is there a deep learning kind of model fit to html situation?
2. break down the problem (to that deep learning model can handle): deal with the `<td></td>` tags separately, classify each tag into items/fields of database using some cnn or rnn text-classification model. Problem is there are possibly many tags contain the same class of information(company name, time, etc.), we can't know which one we want. Maybe we can combine some "position" features of the html, still it's not clearly how to define these features and how to merge these into the classification model to get a somehow end-to-end framework.
3. Is there some better way?

Comment: I've been considering the same problem. I think the lack of response shows how head scratching the problem is even for the experts. There are a number of Machine Learning projects on gitHub that focus on "content extraction" (boilerpipe, readability) but they don't get very specific data.

Comment: Do you have (a few) training samples you can share.  I am working on a deep learning approach for same but its not cooked enough yet to share.  but if the samples are compatible, perhaps we can collaborate.